# Create multiple dependency chains in Project2007

Tags: microsoft-project-2007

I'm a MS Project newbie.

Is there a shortcut for linking a group of tasks into a long chain of dependencies? (In other words, making each task the predecessor of the subsequent one?) For example, in [Open Workbench](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Clarity%20PPM%2013%201%2000%20%20On%20Demand%20-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/owb/index.htm?toc.htm?1902614.html), you can multi-select a group of tasks, then right-click and choose "Make Chain". Is there an efficient way to do the same thing in Project? I entered a huge list of tasks and now I'm manually editing each one and setting the previous task as it's predecessor; there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>[The guy who said there's no dumb questions never met me!]</sub>

If figured it out:

- Select all the tasks that you want to be linked.
- From the Edit menu, choose Link.